# How could I check an input for multiple blanks (" ")?

Tags: python

```py
a = "Am ate rasu"
if " " in a[a.find(" "):]:
    print("Invalid")
else:
    print(a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:a.find(" ")])
```

I want to "scan" the input - in this case it would be the string value of `a` - to check if there are more than one or more blanks `(" ")`.   In this approach, I tried to do so by checking if there were any blanks after the first one, but my issue is that it will continue to detect the blank at `a.find(" ")` and I'm not sure how to get around that.  I have also tried `a.find(" ") + 1` but that didn't work either.

```
from scan_str_module import full_scan as def1
a = input("Full Name: ")
bool1 = def1(a)
if bool1 is False:
    print("Invalid")
else:
    x = a.find(" ")
    name1 = a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:(x)]
    name2 = a.upper()[(x)] + a.lower()[(x)]
    print("First: " + name1)
    print("Last: " + name2)
    print(name1 + " " + name2)
```

Related Issue (Same Project):  The issue lies in the first 3 lines of the `else` statement.  Let's say the input is `"john smith"`.  The `def1` function will "scan" the input for any numeral values returning as True/False.  If it's a valid input, `name1` will be declared as every string value from `j to n` in `john` and `name2` as every string value from `s to h` in `smith`.  It should then print:

```py
First: John
Last: Smith
John Smith
```

But it actually prints something like this:

```py
First: John
Last:
John
```

This happens because the `a.find(" ")` value is actually specified on the blank `(" ")` between `John` and `Smith`.  My issue is that I have no idea how to make it so that `name2` can be specified in the correct `a.find()` value.

Comment: you can use `str.split(' ')` method

Comment: Use the `count` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your current code with a tiny modification: take the string slice starting *after* the first blank, not *at* the first blank:

```
if " " in a[a.find(" ")+1:]:
```

Even easier,

```
if a.count(' ') > 1:
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider, Following code.

```py
if len(a.split(' ')) > 2:
  # 1 space splits 2 words, So If the length of word list > 2, More than 1 spaces are there...
else:
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this also:-

```
a = "Am ate rasu"
if a.count(' ') > 1:
    #####your code
else:
    #####your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything functions correctly now:

First issue:  (Just used `count` function)

```py
a = "Am ate rasu"
if a.count(" ") > 1:
    print("Invalid")
else:
    print(a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:a.find(" ")])
```

Second issue: (Just added more value to the `[a.find(" "):]` values. `+1` and `+2` to position them right.

```py
name1 = a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:a.find(" ")]
name2 = a.upper()[a.find(" ")+1] + a.lower()[a.find(" ")+2:]
```